# How do I create page items in AngularJS if I know the number of pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on a small application that displays a "users" JSON in an *HTML5 table*. It uses Bootstrap 3 and AngularJS. I want to paginate this table.

I do not have an array to loop through, with ng-repeat. I have a *number* the *number of pages*.

With jQuery, I would do:

```js
var pageMax = 10;

var paginationItems = [];
for(var i=0; i<pageMax; i++){
    var paginationItem = '<li><a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>';
    paginationItems.push(paginationItem);
}
var paginationSum = paginationItems.reduce((a, b) => a + b, '');
$('.pagination').html(paginationSum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="text-center">
  <ul class="pagination"></ul>
</div>
```

What is the equivalent of the above for loop in AngularJS?

Comment: any reason not to use [`ui.bootstrap`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination)? e.g. `<ul uib-pagination ...></ul>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular you would do something like this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
   $scope.pageMax = 10;
   
   $scope.pages = new Array($scope.pageMax);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div class="text-center">
    <h3>Initialized in template:</h3>
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(pageMax) track by $index">
          <a href="#">{{$index+1}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <h3>Initialized in controller:</h3>
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li ng-repeat="n in pages track by $index">
          <a href="#">{{$index+1}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There is a `pageMax` variable in my script.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir updated my answer, now you have that variable in the controller.

Comment: It works. Would you provide a short explanation of the code, so that I can *understand* it? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason to use `[].constructor` instead of just `Array`?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir basically it initializes an array with 10 empty values. you could also initialize in the controller.

Comment: I mean `[].constructor(pageMax)` and `Array(pageMax)` should be equivalent.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava You have "merged" two answers that would be more clear if they were separate. Remember that you can give 2 or more answers (solutions).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-repeat` do to this.

Notice that when you want to render the `HTML` you have to use `$sce.trustAsHtml` for AngularJS to actually render the HTML. You can then use `ng-bind-html` in the `HTML`.

```js
var app = angular.module("Dummy", []);

var DummyController = function($scope, $sce) {
  var pageMax = 10;

  $scope.paginationItems = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < pageMax; i++) {
    var item = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a>');
    $scope.paginationItems.push(item);
  }
}

app.controller(DummyController, ["$scope, $sce", "DummyController"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div ng-app="Dummy">
  <div class="text-center" ng-controller="DummyController">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li ng-bind-html="item" ng-repeat='item in paginationItems'></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```